# How to get access into push notification with UI tests (Xcode 12, iOS14)?

Tags: ios, xcode-ui-testing, ios14, xcode12

I'm during migration to work with new Xcode 12, but I have a problem with UI tests.
Code

`let springBoard = XCUIApplication(bundleIdentifier: appleBundleIdentifier) let notification = springBoard.otherElements["NotificationShortLookView"]`

not working anymore and I can't find how to indicate notification view. How was it changed?

Comment: Please add more details in order to explain your question clearly to other users.

Comment: I just want to tap on this notification - `notification.tap()`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems like notification elements have a slightly different accessibility hierarchy in iOS 14. This should work:

```swift
let springBoard = XCUIApplication(bundleIdentifier: "com.apple.springboard")
let notification = springBoard.otherElements["Notification"].descendants(matching: .any)["NotificationShortLookView"]
```

It's interesting to observe that the actual `XCUIElement` that represents the push notification has type "BannerNotification" (an `XCUIElementType` with a rawValue representation 83) which I couldn't find in the public headers. Might be a private type at the moment. Hence the workaround with `decendants(matching: .any)`.

Answer (score 2):

Also accessing/asserting inside the notification is possible:

```
let notification = springBoard.otherElements["Notification"].descendants(matching: .any)["APPNAME, now, TITLE, BODY"]
    if notification.waitForExistence(timeout: 10) {
        notification.tap()
    }
```

Comment: For anyone trying this, it's important to note that `APPNAME` is what shows up in the "title header" of the notification and it is in ALL CAPS. Also, it is an *exact match* on title and body, so even whitespace can make a difference in your assertions.

Answer (score 1):

If anyone is looking for testing if a notification has an attachment, add "Attachment" after notification Body

`let notification = springBoard.otherElements["Notification"].descendants(matching: .any)["APPNAME, now, TITLE, BODY, Attachment"]`